# Delphi thiscall calling convention and class pointer

Tags: c++, delphi, convention

I have a DLL which uses thiscall calling convention.
I've searched trough web and found answer to this question here: [Delphi thiscall calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027412/delphi-thiscall-calling-convention)

Problem I have is that that answer never explains where to get class pointer.
I've tried calling "operator new" function in DLL and it seems to return a valid pointer, but below solution doesn't work for me:
`asm
    mov ecx, myClassPointer
end;`

I'd like a more detailed response, including how to obtain class pointer.

Comment: I don't think you can expect to use this interface directly from Delphi. Write a c++ adapter or get the developer to provide a proper interface. Suppose you crack the calling convention. How are you going to instantiate instances?

Comment: @David is right. `thiscall` is used in classes, and you won't be able to use these directly. You will need a C wrapper or a COM wrapper. See here: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html.

Comment: In the thread I linked, you David said that writing adapters in asm to call the function would work. I just need an example to properly understand how to do that.

Comment: The problem is how you call constructors or pass std::string params etc.

Comment: Amazingly, I got the developer to send me headers and .lib files, so I can now write flattened wrapper. Thank you for the help.